# Azure MSAL Integration not work when app download from play store

Tags: android, azure, azure-ad-msal

I have created mobile app with Azure MSAL integration and use production redirect uri also. mobile app work properly with release apk. but when I uploaded apk to play store and after download from play store app does not work.

this is the error come from

The redirect URI in the configuration file doesn't match with the one generated with package name and signature hash. Please verify the uri in the config file and your app registration in Azure portal.

Comment: Did you manage to find any solution for this?

Comment: Yes.Problem solved .

Comment: @IsuruJayasinghe would you mind posting how you fixed this issue? I'm running into the exact same issue with the signature hash mismatching due to the Google Play signing.

Comment: @IsuruJayasinghe how to fixed this issue?

Comment: @jrend did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @IsuruJayasinghe could you please let me know how you resolved it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may possible, after summiting the apk to Google play store. Google is signing the package with different key that lead to the different hash generation.

You can use the Msal package inspector to get the signature hash of the application. [Package Inspector](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/tree/dev/package-inspector)

if you find the signature of the apk is different from what you added in the config and registered in the Azure Ad then update on both the place.

Comment: This is the right answer. Google is signing the package with different key.

Comment: @Vikrant Singh - how to find the signature hash for the application uploaded in Google play store? I am facing the same issue now and not able to get the signature hash for they key store used by Google in play store for app signing. I downloaded my app from play store, but didn't find the package in package inspector app. TIA.

Comment: @Amardeepvijay could you please let me know how to get signature hash for the app uploaded in playstore?

Comment: @Kameswari Share your app play store link, I will share the key hash for you, or you can run this below link code in your system 

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android

select Package installer package when run.

Comment: @Amardeepvijay - Thanks for the reply. I ran the package inspector and I didn't find my app in that though its installed on the device. I figured out this and issue is resolved now.

Comment: you can also download the certificate Google uses from Play Console -> Releases -> App Integrity -> App Signing key certificate -> download certificate, then run `cat ~\Downloads\deployment_cert.der | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`