# Microsoft MSAL Integration not work when app download from play store

Tags: android, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I have created mobile app with Azure MSAL integration and use production redirect uri also. mobile app work properly with release apk. but when I uploaded apk to play store and after download from play store app does not work.

this is the error come from

The redirect URI in the configuration file doesn't match with the one generated with package name and signature hash. Please verify the uri in the config file and your app registration in Azure portal.

config File

```
{
  "client_id" : "efd193e0-52fe-3495-a66e-699cd8bff715",
  "authorization_user_agent" : "DEFAULT",
  "redirect_uri" : "msauth://com.seuw.kyto/%2Bkdcs24P7wnbe1c6eSY4PZGv5hE%3D",
  "account_mode" : "SINGLE",
  "authorities" : [
    {
      "type": "AAD",
      "audience": {
        "type": "AzureADMyOrg",
        "tenant_id": "1f24ad03-4ab5-34c6-9334-86aedd37af18"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think when publishing your app to the store your debug keys get removed and you didn't provide proper keys.

See https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/wiki/MSAL-FAQ or https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/914

Comment: Please look to this discussion - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59622440/azure-msal-integration-not-work-when-app-download-from-play-store/67509577#67509577

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may possible, after summiting the apk to Google play store. Google is signing the package with different key that led to the different hash generation.

You can use the Msal package inspector to get the signature hash of the application. [Package Inspector](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/tree/dev/package-inspector)

if you find the signature of the apk is different from what you added in the config and registered in the Azure Ad then update on both the place.

Comment: @Diego - how to find the signature hash for the application uploaded in Google play store? I am facing the same issue now and not able to get the signature hash for they key store used by Google in play store for app signing. I downloaded my app from play store, but didn't find the package in package inspector app. TIA.

Comment: @Kameswari get hash in GooglePlay here: the app/Setup/App integrity/SHA-1 , then convert by https://base64.guru/converter/encode/hex

Comment: @Kameswari you need to install and run above code in which written Package Inspector to get signage hash key